# Puppeteer - How to fill form that is inside an iframe?

Tags: puppeteer

I have to fill out a form that is inside an iframe, here the [sample page](http://www.goodmanmfg.com/product-registration). I cannot access by simply using `page.focus()` and `page.type()`. I tried to get the form iframe by using `const formFrame = page.mainFrame().childFrames()[0]`, which works but I cannot really interact with the form iframe.

Comment: What the page look's like, please consider that the other can't help you if we can't see the problem.

Comment: http://www.goodmanmfg.com/product-registration Here's the website. I want to autofill this website and register many serial numbers automatically.

Comment: the page is too heavy, around 6.6 MB.  what puppeteer version you use?

Comment: I'm using the version that is available right now. 0.13.0

Comment: i was unable to continue because, i don't have a valid serial number.

Comment: maybe you can give me sample serial number, so i can properly fill that 3 field.

Comment: 1708020345. There's another page after that asking about the customer information but please don't next after that page.

Comment: Your serial [doesn't have model number](https://github.com/brutalcrozt/travis-reproducer/blob/master/img/heavy.png) , your question is not ready!!

Comment: That's strange, it works for me just fine. [link](https://imgur.com/a/Xmu6U)

Comment: See also [puppeteer #618: Clicking on an element in an iframe fails](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/618) and [puppeteer #684: Clicking element inside iFrame does not give any response](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/684)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I figured it out myself. Here's the code.

```js
console.log('waiting for iframe with form to be ready.');
await page.waitForSelector('iframe');
console.log('iframe is ready. Loading iframe content');

const elementHandle = await page.$(
    'iframe[src="https://example.com"]',
);
const frame = await elementHandle.contentFrame();

console.log('filling form in iframe');
await frame.type('#Name', 'Bob', { delay: 100 });
```

Comment: it seems 'delay' is important here. otherwise it types random stuff. not sure if its a bug or what..

Comment: `$` is redundant. `waitForSelector` already returns element handle.

Answer (score 40):

Instead of figuring out how to get inside the iFrame and type, I would simplify the problem by navigating to the IFrame URL directly

https://warranty.goodmanmfg.com/registration/NewRegistration/NewRegistration.aspx?Sender=Goodman

Make your script directly go to the above URL and try automating, it should work

**Edit-1: Using frames**

Since the simple approach didn't work for you, we do it with the frames itself

Below is a simple script which should help you get started

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://www.goodmanmfg.com/product-registration', { timeout: 80000 });
    var frames = await page.frames();
    var myframe = frames.find(
        f =>
            f.url().indexOf("NewRegistration") > -1);
    const serialNumber = await myframe.$("#MainContent_SerNumText");
    await serialNumber.type("12345");

    await page.screenshot({ path: 'example.png' });

    await browser.close();
})();
```

The output is

[image: Type serial]

Comment: I tried that too. But in the next page, you interact with the iframe and the main frame.

Answer (score 26):

If you can't select/find iFrame read this:

I had an issue with finding stripe elements. 
The reason for that is the following:

> You can't access an  with different origin using JavaScript, it would be a huge security flaw if you could do it. For the same-origin policy browsers block scripts trying to access a frame with a different origin. [See more detailed answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25098153/11974819)

Therefore when I tried to use puppeteer's methods:`Page.frames()` and `Page.mainFrame().`  `ElementHandle.contentFrame()` I did not return any iframe to me. The problem is that it was happening silently and I couldn't figure out why it couldn't find anything.

Adding these arguments to launch options solved the issue:

 `'--disable-web-security',
'--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process'`

Answer (score 3):

Though you have figured out but I think I have better solution. Hope it helps.

```
async doFillForm() {
    return await this.page.evaluate(() => {
       let iframe = document.getElementById('frame_id_where_form_is _present');
       let doc = iframe.contentDocument;
       doc.querySelector('#username').value='Bob';
       doc.querySelector('#password').value='pass123';
    });
}
```