# puppeteer on popup dialog/modal

Tags: node.js, modal-dialog, oracle-apex, puppeteer

Appreciate if anyone can help

Running in to this issue and searching around has not yielded a result regarding the puppeteer dialog modal. As such I am struggling to determine which path to take.

[modal dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPaMH.png)

This modal dialog  appears when clicking on :

```js
await frame.click ("ul#P11_MAIN_CONTAINER_cards a:nth-child(1) > span")
```

This oracle Apex dialog.modal doesn't seem to have id or name only src. I am unable to access the elements in this dialog/modal .

I wonder if you have any guidance on this issue type, furthermore how does puppeteer cater to this type of "popup"

contentFrame[0] is valid
contentFrame[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMIny.png) is valid  at the base page.

- unable to get the iframe inside the dialog/modal
- this oracle apex modal dialog appears after the click and thus blocks the puppeteer, so how does one go about handling [dialog/modal](https://www.apex-at-work.com/2013/10/jquery-modaldialog-with-iframe.html)?  popup?
- does this require a `targetcreated` method?  if so how does target created work on this part?
- or does a new tab ( like this below ) require a `const page2 = await browser.newPage();`?

```css
 tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="ui-dialog ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-front ui-dialog--apex t-Dialog--wizard ui-draggable ui-resizable" aria-describedby="apex_dialog_1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" style="position: fixed; height: 90%; width: 90%; top: 5%; left: 5%; max-width: 100%;">.........
```

Appreciate if anyone have anything to share.

```js
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const config = require('../lib/config')
const homePage  =  require('../pages/HomePage')
const homePageObjects = require('../pageObjects/homePageObjects')
const loginPage  =  require('../pages/LoginPage')
const helper = require('../lib/helper')


describe('Home Menu Tests',() => {
    let browser
    let page

    
    before(async function(){
        browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
            headless:config.isHeadless,
            slowMo:config.slowMo,
            devtools:config.isDevtools,
            timeout:config.launchTimeout,
            Args: ['--disable-notifications','--disable-web-notification-custom-layouts'
            ,'--user-data-dir=/home/aspats3/ess/profile','--disable-features=site-per-process' ],
            executablePath:'/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable',
         
            
        })
        
        page = await browser.newPage()
        
        page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
        await page.setDefaultTimeout(config.waitingTimeout)
        await page.setViewport({
            width:config.viewRepotWidth,
            height:config.viewRepotHeight,  
      
        })
       

  
        await helper.loadUrl(page,config.baseUrl);
        await loginPage.Login(page,'AB0001','concept');

    })

    //after(async function() {
      //  await homePage.Logout(page)
        //await browser.close()
        
    //})
    


    it('Verify My Team - List  ',async()=>{
         
 
        await page.reload({ waitUntil: ["networkidle0", "domcontentloaded"] });
        await helper.hover(page,homePageObjects.homeMenu);
        await page.waitFor(3000);
        await helper.clickX(page,"//a[@id='WJ2000']");
        await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: ["networkidle0", "domcontentloaded"] });
        await page.waitFor(8000);
        //await helper.shouldExistX (page,"//*[contains(.,'Team Details')]")
        //await helper.shouldExistX (page,"//*[contains(.,'Management')]")
        //await helper.shouldExistX (page,"//*[contains(.,'Leave')]")
        //await helper.shouldExistX (page,"//*[contains(.,'Timesheets')]")
        await page.waitForSelector('iframe');
        await page.waitForSelector('#P1_IFRAME')
        console.log('childFrames count:', page.mainFrame().childFrames().length);
        console.log('pageFrames count:', page.frames().length);

        const iframeHandles = await page.$$('iframe');
        
        console.log('contentFrame[0] is valid:', await iframeHandles[0].contentFrame() !== null);
        console.log('contentFrame[1] is valid:', await iframeHandles[1].contentFrame() !== null);


        const elementHandle = await page.$('div#P1_LAUNCHER iframe');
        const frame = await elementHandle.contentFrame();
        await page.waitFor(8000);


        const newPagePromise = new Promise(x => browser.on('targetcreated', target => x(target.frame()))); 
        
    
        await frame.click ("ul#P11_MAIN_CONTAINER_cards a:nth-child(1) > span")   click this for dialog modal iframe
  
  
        await frame.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: ["networkidle0", "domcontentloaded"] });
        await page.waitFor(20000);
  
  
  //  from  here on cant get into dialog modal iframe ( nested iframe ) 
               //`
```

Comment: Have you tried `page.frames`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46529201/puppeteer-how-to-fill-form-that-is-inside-an-iframe

Comment: @Dan McGhan   appreciate the reply @ these crazy time.
 its kinda new to this learning as i  get into it.  this base page  loads an iframe   . Click the button frame.click ("ul#P11_MAIN_CONTAINER_cards a:nth-child(1) > span")  

then this popup modal occurs , so had difficulty on accessing this modal dialog page .   so to answer this , yes i have tried that.  

with :

        //const frame1 = await page.frames().find(f => f.url().includes('f?p=110:5:'))

        //const frames = await page.frames();
        //console.log('frame>>>', await frames[1].name());

still figuring out .

Answer (score 2):

What you can do solve your issue is to create a new async function and inside of it you can put Puppeteer's `page.evaluate()` function. Then click on the button and load up the modal (grab the modal by its `aria-labbelledby` attribute) and put its contents inside a variable. This entire function should be **outside** of your main function.

Then in your main function you can call this `grabTheModal()` function after you go to the URL.

You can do all that like this:

```
let modalContents;

const grabTheModal = async(page) => {
    await page.evaluate(async () => {
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            frame.click ("ul#P11_MAIN_CONTAINER_cards a:nth-child(1) > span")
            setTimeout(() => {
                const modal = document.querySelector('[aria-labelledby=ui-id-2]'); // Grab the modal by its aria label
                modalContents = modal.innerHTML;
                resolve();
            }, 500)
        });
    });
}

const getModalContents = async() => {
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    let page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'load'}); //Remember to add your own URL in the url variable
    await grabTheModal(page);
    await browser.close();
    console.log(modalContents)
}
getModalContents();
```

Comment: appreciate this . will give it a go . will report back.

Comment: @bbr I see that I actually made a mistake. I'm calling the wrong function inside of the `getModalContents()`. I've fixed it now, so maybe just retry this. Sorry about that.

Comment: nothing to it , i am still thinking/wrapping my head around this approach. really appreciate for the path/direction shown. will report back.