# How to get challenge key from a target website using geetest captcha

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, captcha, apify

So I am scraping data from a target website using puppeteer.
Target website used geetest captcha, for anti-captcha, I am using 2capcta service,
on their documentation, it's mentioned that we need to get the challenge key every time.

From that the problem begins, target website has embedded the challenge key under

```
<Iframe>
<Html>
<head>
<script>
```

when accessing the iframe through DOM elements throw me a CORS error.

I have tried another way also which is available on the scraper box link is below

```
https://scraperbox.com/blog/solving-a-geetest-slider-captcha-with-puppeteer
```

it throws me no selector `'[aria-label="Click to verify"]'` found

it tried the codegrepper way link is below

```
https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/puppeteer+get+network+requests
```

throw me on console.error().

Any help would be appreciated to bypass geetest captcha
let me know also if my question is unclear.

Comment: The selector that can't be found is from the Geetest demo site. It most likely is different on this target website you are referring to. The CORS error is expected or else that would be a huge security flaw. Nothing stopping you from going to the `<iframe>` link directly though. You can find more about using `puppeteer` with an `<iframe>` here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46529201/puppeteer-how-to-fill-form-that-is-inside-an-iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much for the answer,
so with the response by the above gentleman, the final solution is

when you load your page through puppeteer

```
   await page.waitForSelector('iframe');
```

this will wait till the time iframe is loaded, now for me the target website has use the iframe with hash link to access it

```
const elementHandle = await page.$('iframe');
const frame = await elementHandle.contentFrame();
```

now the frame will have access to your iframe page, so you use the rest same like

```
 await frame.waitForSelector("your selector")
```